# mysql connection not working on JSP deployment using tomcat

Tags: mysql, linux, jsp, jdbc, tomcat6

I developed my enterprise application using Java EE. This uses JDBC for mysql connection. The project works fine when its run from the intellij idea IDE. But after i deployed it with the same version of tomcat, JDBC connector and all the other libraries as used during development.
The login page is browsed but as soon i login after providing all the credentials, it throws out an error in form of exception along with 500 error which i believe is due to connection failure to mysql.
The error message is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    utils.DatabaseConnection.getPreparedStatement(DatabaseConnection.java:34)
    services.UserService.getUser(UserService.java:31)
    controller.SessionServlet.doPost(SessionServlet.java:30)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

[snapshot of error after login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq1po.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: Blind guess: Connection variable not initialized when trying to create a PreparedStatement - show the code for DatabaseConnection (Line 34 especially!)

Comment: This actually worked in the PC i had developed,it is a deployment issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because Java could not communicate with mysql. This led null pointer for a variable related to username and password. It was due to misconfiguration for database connection. I entered wrong informations.